# Go REST API handle empty url parameters

Tags: rest, go

I wonder how to handle endpoint with given empty parameter, for example one endpoint of my API is

`...url/item/{id}`

and it's implementation is

```
func GetItem(c *gin.Context){
    id := c.Param("id")
    ...
}
```

Should I handle empty `id` by

```
if id == ""{
    //handle if empty
    return
}
```

or it's not necessary to validate it?

I think about it because you can call endpoint method from unit test and the question is if it's possible to hack it somehow and call endpoint with empty `id`, which may cause some fatal errors?

Answer (score 0):

You should prevent it at your routing layer rather than when you're getting the path parameters.

```
router.GET("/user/:name", func(c *gin.Context) {
        name := c.Param("name")
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "Hello %s", name)
    })
```

In this snippet from the `gin` documentation it basically describes a similar get endpoint where it expects you to have a `:name` parameter, which maps to your `id` parameter. If the route is invoked without an `id` parameter it'll not route to that function.